# identify a file with specific chars present in it and rename the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I am trying to find and rename below files using below script

```
IYBR2C.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190503170641.csv to SAK_BB_AL.csv
QWEJ1P.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190508122932.csv to SAM_SG_MO.csv
SCPR1C.YGPSWS.SL.1.T.20190503164120.csv to SVM_SG_AL.csv
SMCE2P.SGPAWS.SL.1.T.20190508123138.csv to SDM_SG_MO.csv
```

This is what I have tried for a single file:

But my problem is I need to have some conditions on this renaming that is

```
ex-:
IYBR2C.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190503170641.csv to SAK_BB_AL.csv
```

for this example file I need to check whether it starts with "IYBR2C" and it contains "M" if this two conditions are met then rename it to SAK_BB_AL.csv

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(/tmp):
for dir in dirs:
    if dir.startswith("IYBR2C"):
        org_fp = os.path.join(root, dir)
        new_fp = os.path.join(root, dir[1])
        os.rename(org_fp, new_fp)
```

what I have tried gives no results as expected to find the file and rename it which starts with ("IYBR2C") and How can I check that it contains the letter ("M") as well.

Note : Files are present in my /tmp directory and I do not know how many of them are there I provided an example as to how I can achieve it for `IYBR2C.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190503170641.csv` , please provide a general solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going. you basically need two conditions in the if statement, checking first word and search for character in the name. Here is a mockup. Tell me if it is okay.

```
filenames=['IYBR2C.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190503170641.csv',
'QWEJ1P.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190508122932.csv',
'SCPR1C.YGPSWS.SL.1.T.20190503164120.csv',
'SMCE2P.SGPAWS.SL.1.T.20190508123138.csv']
for newname in filenames:
         if(newname.split('.')[0]=='IYBR2C' and "M" in newname):
                print newname,'SAK_BB_AL.csv'
```

Result:

```
IYBR2C.YGPSWS.SL.1.M.20190503170641.csv SAK_BB_AL.csv
```

Comment: Thanks , but was thinking about this implementation for each file I need to place a for loop ?
suppose I have other files as well if you see in the list, the one which you provided solution was only an example now for `QWEJ1P` also i need to da a `for` loop ?
and I cannot keep this files in a array because I dont know how many of them are there like this in my `/tmp` directory

Comment: It is also fine. you just need to put the if condition in your loop.

Comment: But I want to rename it , current code only prints the file doesnt rename in the directory How to rename it ?

Comment: Using `os.rename("newname","SAK_BB_AL.csv")` gives error file not found

Comment: okay, your newname should be org_fp. So to rename you do:  os.rename(org_fp,"SAK_BB_AL.csv")